# Average noise level graph on Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, audio

Using a laptop's microphone, I want a graph showing the level of noise during a certain period:

[image: Noise graph]

Noise needs to be sampled at a high rate and averaged over one minute or so.
The output can be as simple as appending one line to a CSV file every minute.

Requirements:

- Runs on Linux
- Free, ideally open source
- Calculate average for a minute, not instant value
- Output to text file or image
- Bonus if it can "filter out" usual background noise, in order to better show anormal noise (a "training" could be required to specify what the usual background noise is)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [python](http://python.org) [soundmeter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/soundmeter) library.

- Runs on Linux
- Libre & FOSS
- You can average in a number of ways
- You can either output to a text file or use one of the plotting libraries
- Measures the RMS value.

Comment: On Ubuntu 2014.04, `soundmeter` requires `portaudio19-dev` which requires `libjack-dev` which requires `libjack0`. Installing `libjack0` removes `libjack-jackd2-0` and `skype` which is no go :-/

Comment: Have you considered a) Raising a ticket or b) porting to work with libjackd2-0 - tickets can be raised at https://github.com/shichao-an/soundmeter/issues and shichao-an seems to be approachable.

Comment: I guess this is an Ubuntu packaging problem with ` portaudio19-dev` or maybe just an incompatibility with Skype.

Comment: I have seen quite a lot of online comments regarding issues with both `skype` and `libjack-jackd2-0` but I would still recommend raising a ticket to record the issue if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small bash script to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
>data.txt
while true
do
  sox -t .wav "|arecord -d 1" -n stat 2>&1 | grep "RMS     amplitude" \
  | tr -d ' ' | cut -d ':' -f 2 >> data.txt
done
```

I takes the RMS every second and writes it to a text file.

A graph can be generated using this Gnuplot script (put it in a with `graph.gnuplot` file and run `gnuplot graph.gnuplot`):

```
set yrange [0:0.1]
set grid
set term png
set output 'graph.png'
plot 'data.txt' with line lt -1 lw 1
```